# Java: Polymorphic Return Type in an Abstract Method?

Tags: java, gwt, parametric-polymorphism

I have the following code in an abstract java class:

```
protected abstract <E extends HasText & IsWidget> E createNewDisplayWidget();
```

Which compiles fine. However if I call it anywhere, the compiler complains:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method createNewDisplayWidget() of type DemoClass is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type HasText is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends HasText & IsWidget>
```

Is there a way to require an abstract method to return something that should implement multiple interfaces?

Note: No, I cannot create a special interface that implements the two I like. GWT has widgets like Label which already implement said interfaces and I would like to use said widget.

Edit: I got the idea to do this from here (page 22):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Comment: Have you tried with a comma instead of an and?

Comment: a comma would mean that the bound ends at IsWidget. HasText then gets ignored. The compiler throws a warning saying that the second type is 'hidden'.

Comment: Can you show us one/some of your call sites?

Comment: I don't believe this is actually possible.  Return an actual class in that intersection.

Comment: Could you confirm your call-site is something like `HasText t = createNewDisplayWidget()` with an implicit (or explicit) `HasText` type argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in Eclipse. I upgraded from 3.7 to 3.7.2 and the compiler error went away.

I don't know the details of what effect this had. If someone has a clue please feel free to update my answer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The [release notes of Eclipse 3.7.1](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.7.1.html#DefectsFixed) lists the fixed [Bug 341795](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341795), which describes the same situation, with exactly the error message you saw!

Answer (score 2):

I have given a try on the basis of your question and i was able to get through without an error. Please check the classes that i have created.

**TestClass**

```
public abstract class TestClass {

    protected abstract <E extends HasText & IsWidget > E createNewDisplayWidget();

}
```

**HasText class**

```
public class HasText {

}
```

**IsWidget**

```
public interface IsWidget {

}
```

**DemoClass**

```
 public class DemoClass extends HasText implements IsWidget{

    }
```

**TestClass1**

```
public class TestClass1 extends TestClass{

    @Override
    protected DemoClass createNewDisplayWidget() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DemoClass type = new DemoClass();
        return type;
    }

    public void checkOut(){
        if(createNewDisplayWidget() instanceof HasText || createNewDisplayWidget() instanceof IsWidget){
            System.out.println("Yes it works");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("It doesnt");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestClass1 check = new TestClass1();
        check.checkOut();

    }

}
```

When i run my main program i always get "Yes it works". Please let me know am i missing something.

Comment: You're calling `createNewDisplayWidget()` from the same class where you gave it a more concrete return type. I tried calling it from `DemoClass` but couldn't reproduce the OP's error. Maybe it's a GWT-specific problem.

Comment: Yes. The problem I was trying to get around was not having to create another type like "DemoClass". It's actually the solution I went with, but it's not what I was looking for because now I have to create custom types for every class from GWT I wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried doing the complete code to generate the error, but for some reason it didn't give an error. Will look into it in a bit:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public abstract class DemoClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoClass dc = new DemoClassImpl();
        dc.createNewLivingAndDying().live();
        dc.killAll();
    }

    LinkedList<Dies> dying = new LinkedList<Dies>();

    public Lives createNewLivingAndDying() {
        Lives ab = newLivingAndDying(); // This is where I expected an error
        dying.add((Dies) ab);
        return ab;
    }

    public void killAll() {
        for (Dies dead : dying)
            dead.die();
    }

    protected abstract <E extends Lives & Dies> E newLivingAndDying();

}

class DemoClassImpl extends DemoClass {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected <E extends Lives & Dies> E newLivingAndDying() {
        return (E) new SomePrivateClass(); // This is what I don't understand
    }

}

interface Lives {
    public void live();
};

interface Dies { 
    public void die();
};

class SomePrivateClass implements Lives, Dies {

    @Override
    public void die() {
        System.out.println("Object Dies");
    }

    @Override
    public void live() {
        System.out.println("Object Lives");
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs fine on my home computer but giver the error on my work computer.

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method newLivingAndDying() of type DemoClass is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type Lives is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Lives & Dies>
```

At this point I think it's a project setup issue but I don't know what it is. JRE 1.6 both.

Comment: In other words, you bypass the error by using `Object` (implicitly) as the type argument and then casting to either one interface. Put differently if you only need a `Lives` somewhere, `Lives lives = newLivingAndDying()` would fail to compile, but `Lives lives = (Lives) this.<Object>newLivingAndDying()` would compile (and work!)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer `<Object>newLivingAndDying()` won't compile:) the reason why `Object ab = newLivingAndDying();` compiles is complicated, arguably due to quirks in type inference.

Comment: @McTrafik, by casting, an implementation can return anything, regardless of declared return type. that's fine, but you lose compiler type checking. you may as well declare `Object newLivingAndDying()`.

Comment: @irreputable I'm writing a library, and my goal is not let developers implement the method without implementing proper interfaces or using classes that do. Perhaps I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Eum, no. I didn't have to use `Object`. I could have just as easily said `Lives ab = newLivingAndDying();` without any casts.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is only possible if Java supports interception type directly, then you can simply

```
   HasText&IsWidget createNewDisplayWidget();
```

any implementation must return an object that's a subtype of the type `HasText&IsWidget`; in another word, the returned type must be a subtype of both `HasText` and `IsWidget`

Unfortunately, Java does not support that.

The problem of your attempted solution can be understood from two angles:

1) constraints on a type variable are constraints on the caller; caller supplies the actual type argument, and it must satisfy the constraints. What you really want is constraints on the callee.

2) if a type variable only appears in the return type, but not types of method parameters, it is *usually* a sign of problem. In Java, due to the evil *type erasure*, the method body cannot know the runtime type argument, therefore it cannot return a value of proper type desired by caller, except for some trivial values like `null`; another classic example of trivial return value is

```
java.util.Collections  
    <T> Set<T> emptySet()
```

Comment: The answer is not correct, and you shouldn't accept it. What is correct is, that such a method signature *may* be a sign of a problem. But for a factory that creates a certain set of subtypes, this may be ok (for convenience), and it works in Java (just add the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), if you like. You may get ClassCastExceptions at Runtime, and it may not always be the nicest approach, but **this does not explain the compiler error you are getting**!

Comment: To me `In Java, due to the evil type erasure, the method body cannot know the runtime type argument, therefore it cannot return a value of proper type desired by caller` made sense as the reason. I tried adding a parameter  of type `E` to the signature and the compiler stopped complaining. Of course then the method becomes unusable.